# How to return middle element of list?

Tags: common-lisp

How to define function which returns the middle element of list, assuming an odd number of elements?

(all-but-last list) returns all but the last element of list;
(middle list) returns the middle element of list

to make use of "cdr" and "all-but-last" for the definition of “middle.”

Comment: Try to ask question by showing what you have done so far rather asking "how to ..." or "where to ..." And take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This is a probably a homework question which expects you to solve the problem recursively. 
You should try to distinguish the base cases of the recursion to build up the general definition of `middle`. Also, we stick to the problem and assume there is always an odd number of elements in the input list.

So first, what is the middle of a list with a single element ?

Then, given that you *have* to use `cdr` and `all-but-last` as basic constructs, try to define the problems using those constructs for the general case. How can you reduce the problem into recursive sub-problems using those constructs? How do you combine the recursive results to make a result?

For example, try with the next odd-sized list, a list of 3 elements and try to see how you could find the middle element using your basic construct and a recursive call.

> Consider a list with elements *a, e0, e1, ..., en, z*. Then the middle of  this list is the same as the middle of the list *e0, e1, ..., en*, namely the list with the first and last elements removed.

You could start with something like this, and fill the blanks:

```
(defun middle (list)
  (if (endp (cdr list))
      ...
      (middle ...)))
```